# Spring controller keeps old value

Tags: java, spring, controller, code-injection

I'm developing a system using Spring injection. During a certain point, there's a warning on the screen that is shown using an attribute on a WarningHelper class, which is a Spring Controller. Following is summarized code:

```
@Controller
@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)
public class WarningHelper implements Serializable {
     //Bunch of attributes
     private String warningText;

     //Bunch of other methods

     private String configureWarning(Integer caller, Outcome outcome, WarningReturn warningReturn, GlobalWebUser user) {
            //business logic

    if (hasWarning()) {
        setWarningText(warningReturn.getWarningText());
    }

    return redirect;
 }
}
```

That part works perfectly. Later on, a xhtml page shows this warning using another controller in which this first one is injected. Following is the edited code for the second controller:

```
@Controller
@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_APPLICATION)
public class CustomUrlController {

    //Bunch of other attributes
@Inject
private WarningHelper warningHelper;    

    //Bunch of methods
    public String getAllMessages() {
        String completeMessage = "";
        //business logic creating the message
        completeMessage += warningHelper.getWarningText();

        return complete Message
    }   
}
```

This all works just fine the first time around. The problem is that if I try then to enter another profile which has a different message, the first one is still shown. Note that this change process does not involve another login, so the session is still the same. I have tried toying around with the scope, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)` as `@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)`  in both **WarningHelper** and **CustomUrlController** class. This will instantiate the `CustomUrlController` and  `warningHelper` for every request.

Comment: Seems that it worked. I'll test some more, but preliminary tests are good! Thanks!